# How to sketch an image and find set of this function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

$ c\left(t\right) =\begin{pmatrix} e^{t}  \\ e^{-t} \end{pmatrix} $

How do I find set and geometric object of $ c\left(\mathbb R \right) $ ?

I know the graph of $e^{t}$  and $e^{-t}$, but how to put it all together in geometric object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $x = e^t$ and $y = e^{-t}$ and note that $xy = 1$. Thus,

$$ c(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \{ (x,y) \, | \, xy = 1 \} $$

and the set $\{ (x,y) \, | \, xy = 1 \}$ is a hyperbola with two connected components. Now note that $e^t > 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and so $x > 0$ and thus the image $c(\mathbb{R})$ lies only in the component of the hyperbola that lies in the first quadrant. Finally, let us show that indeed

$$ c(\mathbb{R}) = \{ (x,y) \, | \, xy = 1, x > 0 \}. $$

If $xy = 1$ and $x > 0$, we can take $t = \ln(x)$ and then 
$$ c(t) = (e^t, e^{-t}) = (e^{\ln x}, e^{- \ln x}) = \left( x, \frac{1}{x} \right) = (x,y). $$